# Memory re-allocation when inserting to std::map inside of std::vector

Tags: c++, performance, memory, memory-management, stdmap

I have a data structure that looks like:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::map<float, float>>>
```

The outer map has a fixed number of dimensions (around 5), as well as the inner vector (# of pixels). Currently I am dynamically adding elements to the inner map. The number of elements in the map is small, around 10.

This is really slow; having read other SO posts, it seems due to memory re-allocation when inserting to the map.

Is there an alternate way I could structure this data so that the memory re-allocation isn't (as big of) an issue? Possibly due to the fact that my outer vector/map have a fixed size? I have already tried an unsorted_map (for the inner map), but that actually decreased performance - I think this could be due to the small map size (& related hashing overhead).

I also wondered if the memory re-allocation upon inner map insertion implies that the memory for the parent vector/map is also re-allocated? Is that why my code performs so poorly?

Any pointers at all would be appreciated!

Comment: when you insert something to the innermost map, no reallocation of the outer map or vector is needed. If you have some code that needs improvement, better include a [mcve] of that code in the question

Comment: With so few items in the map, it'd probably be more performant to switch from a map to a vector.  Profile, profile, profile.  If vector turns out to be better, make sure you comment your code why a vector is being used instead of the map, since it appears a map is the natural fit.

Comment: @Eljay, do you imply a vector of pairs in that case?

Comment: Could be done with pairs:  `vector<pair<string, vector<pair<float, float>>>>`  Or you could use `tuple`, or you could use declare a `struct`.

Comment: 1. `std::vector::reserve` should help. 2. did you do a profiling? Are you sure you are blaming proper part of code?

Comment: Two pieces of information are missing: (1) how big are the vectors, and most importantly (2) what are you doing with this data? CRUD? Or just search? For what?